# find second highest from each group in sql?

Tags: mysql, database

i have table structure like this

```
'encounterID' , 'dateAndTime'

1234          2016-02-12 17:57:57
1234          2016-02-12 17:58:59
1234          2016-02-12 17:59:05

12345         2016-02-12 17:57:57
12345         2016-02-12 17:58:59
12345         2016-02-12 17:59:05
```

i want to find second latest entry for every encounterId?

Anyone Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to select top-n-per-group records:

```
SELECT encounterID, dateAndTime
FROM (
  SELECT encounterID, dateAndTime,
         @rn := IF(@eID = encounterID, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@eID := encounterID, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @eID := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY encounterID, dateAndTime DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 2
```

The outer query selects the second latest record per `encounterID` group.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0439/3)